# Customize size for drawing box in matrix

Tags: matrices, framed

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usepackage{amsmath,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Matrix}

This is an example of a matrix.

\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix [matrix of math nodes,left delimiter=(,right delimiter=),ampersand replacement=\&] (m)
{
  8 \& 8 \& 1 \& 6 \\
  3 \& 8 \& 5 \& 7 \\
  4 \& 8 \& 9 \& 5 \\
};
\draw[color=red, thick] (m-1-1.north west) -- (m-1-3.north east) -- (m-2-3.south east) -- (m-2-1.south west) -- (m-1-1.north west);
\draw[color=blue, thick] (m-2-1.north west) -- (m-2-3.north east) -- (m-3-3.south east) -- (m-3-1.south west) -- (m-2-1.north west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I drew two boxes in a matrix (in Beamer). It works, except that the two boxes partially overlap, and so the blue box is laid over the red box in part, which is not very nice.

Is there a way to perhaps make the blue box larger or smaller, so that they don't overlap? (Other ways of avoiding the overlap are welcome too.)

Comment: Your boxes seems to intentionally drawn such ... they framed 6 nodes. Can you elaborate, which matrix nodes each box should framed?

Comment: The nodes that the framed are correct. It's just that the edges of the boxes overlap, so some part of the red box disappears because of the blue box. So I was to change the size of the blue box, so that they don't overlap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's suppose you expect something like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usepackage{amsmath,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,matrix}
\tikzset{
mN/.style = {%myNode
    draw=#1, thick, inner sep=0pt}
             }

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Matrix}

This is an example of a matrix.

    \begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix [matrix of math nodes, column sep=1pt,
         left delimiter=(,right delimiter=),ampersand replacement=\&] (m)
{
  8 \& 8 \& 1 \& 6 \\
  3 \& 8 \& 5 \& 7 \\
  4 \& 8 \& 9 \& 5 \\
};
\node[mN=red, xshift= 2pt, fit=(m-1-1) (m-2-3)] {};
\node[mN=blue,xshift=-2pt, fit=(m-2-1) (m-3-3)] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
    \end{document}
```

**Edit:** I slightly optimized the code.